# default language codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

i want to run this code at the first of all my webpages,

I'm using codeigniter

**the code is:**

```
if(!$this->session->userdata('lang')):
$this->session->set_userdata('lang','ar');
endif;
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, it may be worth looking at CodeIgniter's [language class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html).

---

You can extend the native `CI_Controller` class. Extending this class allows you to add your additional functionality, while the original functionality of the native core class remains.

For the code to run first on all pages, you can add your code to the constructor of the newly created subclass - if you extend your controller(s) with the new subclass, then this code will be run when any function in your controller(s) is called. To do this:

**Create a subclass**

Create a file named `MY_Controller.php` in the `application/core/` directory of your project. This new class needs to extend `CI_Controller` and the parent constructor. The class should look something like this:

```
<?php    

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();  //make sure you extend the parent constructor

        //Your code:
        if( ! $this->session->userdata('lang') )
            $this->session->set_userdata('lang','ar');
    }

}
```

**Ensure the class prefix is correct**

If you've used `MY_` as the prefix for the new class then you shouldn't need to do anything here, but it's useful to know anyway.

You'll also need to ensure that the sub-class prefix is set correctly in the `application/config/config.php` file.

```
$config['subclass_prefix'] = 'MY_';
```

This prefix must match the prefix of the new class that you create. By default it is `MY_` but you can change it to what you want as long as they correspond - `FOO_`, `BAR_`, `WHATEVER_`... The exception is `CI_`, which is reserved for CodeIgniter's native libraries.

**Extend all of you application's controller with the new subclass**

Your controller(s) in `application/controllers/` is(/are) probably extending `CI_Controller`. To make use of the newly created subclass, your controller should extend `MY_Controller` and the parent constructor.

```
class Welcome extends MY_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    } 

    //More functions...
}
```

Comment: No problem, I'm pleased it worked! If you've found the answer useful, then maybe you could consider marking it as correct/upvoting? http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask